# Accessing the original run list in a recipe

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I would like to access the original run list in a chef recipe when doing an override.  Is there an object available to already do this ?  right now I get:

```
[2016-04-12T20:14:27+00:00] WARN: Run List override has been provided.
[2016-04-12T20:14:27+00:00] WARN: Original Run List: [role[foo], role[bar]]
[2016-04-12T20:14:27+00:00] WARN: Overridden Run List: [recipe[baz]]
```

In recipe[baz] I would like to know that role[foo] is in the node's default run list.

something similar to this:

```
if node.original_runlist.includes?('role[foo]')
    do_something
else
    do_something_else
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As noted in a comment above, i found node.primary_runlist.  In the event someone else is interested:

```
run_list = node.primary_runlist
if run_list.includes?('role[foo]')
    do_something
else
    do_something_else
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Most attributes are set by Ohai at the start of a chef run.
You may try to run ohai as first command in your cookbooks and catch output to get the full list of basic Ohai attributes.
But anyway following attributes should be available from recipes:
`node['recipes']`   A list of recipes associated with a node (and part of that node’s run-list).
`node['roles']`     A list of roles associated with a node (and part of that 
node’s run-list).
More details [here](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#automatic-ohai)

Comment: vvchik, thank you for your reply.  I actually looked through the code, and found the client is doing node.primary_runlist.  This provides me what i was looking for.